# illustrator actions - live trace settings

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, vector, illustrator-scripting

I'm trying to set a macro to batch vectorize png to svg vectors, but i'm stuck at the Live Trace action. Illustrator will only use the default preset, how can overwrite the default preset OR create an action using a custom preset ?

i use illustrator CS6

Comment: You might have better luck asking at the official Adobe Illustrator Scripting forums: https://forums.adobe.com/community/illustrator/illustrator_scripting

Answer (score 2):

You can do this via scripting, a quick template example:

```
var traceobj = selection[0].trace();
var opt = traceobj.tracing.tracingOptions;

opt.cornerAngle = 90;
opt.fills = true;
opt.ignoreWhite = false;
opt.maxColors = 32;
opt.maxStrokeWeight = 0;
opt.minArea = 5;
opt.minStrokeLength = 3;
opt.outputToSwatches = true;
opt.palette = '';
opt.pathFitting = true;
opt.preprocessBlur = 0;
opt.strokes = false;
// threshold = 120 // BW only
opt.tracingMode = TracingModeType.TRACINGMODECOLOR

traceobj.tracing.tracingOptions = opt;
```

Comment: How do you use it?