# Illustrator Action : Remove a vertical line after using pathfinder tool

Tags: adobe-illustrator, automation, actions

I am trying to generate outline from thousands of images and then cut them in half. I want to automate it. I made Illustrator action which is working really good. The only thing I am not being able to automate is to delete the vertical line (Shown in the picture) to make the path open.

Any idea how to automate it?

I am creating a rectangle to cut the shape in half so if there is a hidden Pathfinder shortcut or tool that leaves the path open after cropping that I can incorporate in the action, that will help too.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To be clear, you want to have an open path?

Comment: Yes. It has to be open.

Comment: You should be able to create a script that uses the direct select tool (the white arrow) to select and delete the unwanted line.

Comment: @13ruce: Thanks for the suggestion. I am not a programmer and would like to avoid script if possible.

Comment: @13ruce I was thinking that... for this shape, it would be pretty simple (just a straight line) but I imagine that it would fail on more complex shapes with more than one line and other variations etc.

Comment: Then perhaps make a selection of everything up to .001pt to the left of the center line, then inverse the selection and delete? That should account for any breaks in the vertical line.

Comment: @CrimsonCape I don't think you're going to be able to automate this without using scripts. The Pathfinder always closes paths. Scripting should not scare you off. I'm no programmer, and every script I make is cobbled together from examples I find. Scripts are so powerful that it's worth the effort. Give the scope of your project, it is absolutely worth looking into getting a script to do the heavy lifting.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. In your *sample* it may be easy to target the *only* vertical path, but chances are for most artwork there won't be just one, single, vertical path. You may do better with a script utilizing **Divide** and then deleting the right side after divide.

Comment: @13ruce: Can you kindly tell me how to insert a script into an action? I am looking into that kind of script now. Thanks.

Comment: You wouldn't need to insert the script into an action. It would be more efficient to do everything with one script. You can run a script on all of the files in a folder with something like:
<b>sourceFolder = Folder.selectDialog();<b>
pagesToProcess = sourceFolder.getFiles("*.ai");<b>
Like I said, I'm no coder, so this is just a snippet I found. It would be added to the top of the script you use to process your vectors.

Comment: @13ruce: Thanks. I am trying to develop one.

Comment: Here's a good source:  https://illustrator-scripting-guide.readthedocs.io/

Comment: And here's another:  https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/illustrator/pdf/Illustrator_Scriptin_Reference_JavaScript_cc.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Save the script below as openpath.jsx or whatever with .jsx and automate it with your batch.

File > Scripts > Other Scripts

```
for (var i=0;i<app.activeDocument.pathItems.length;i++)  
  if (app.activeDocument.pathItems[i].closed==true)  
  app.activeDocument.pathItems[i].closed=false ;
```

Since the boolean operation redefines the starting and closing points of a path, hopefully this will work in all cases.

**EDIT**

Since the shapes are irregular, following procedure can be used to achieve the desired result.

```
1) Change the fill to outline for the object that is supposed to be retained
2) Change the fill to white color for the second object (cutter)
3) Select both objects and use Ojbect > Expand (Expand Fill and Stroke)
4) Path Finder > Minus Front
```

Comment: It looks like this is just going to open closed paths. I think the OP wants the vertical line to go away entirely.

Comment: @Tough Guy: Hi, I tried the script. It does open the path however, since the shapes are being created by automation, there are segments that marks the start and end of a path and is not necessarily always that vertical line. Thanks for the script though.

Comment: @13ruce opening the path means deleting the line between first and last points. So the line goes away entirely.

Comment: @CrimsonCape As I mentioned earlier, the boolean operation `(Minus front)` redifines the start and end points of a path. If the script is automated right after the boolean operation, it will delete the vertical line that was created with boolean operation.

Comment: @CrimsonCape If you are using two irregular shapes in boolean operation (e.g. circle with circle) and then expecting the resulting image to cut between center, then adding a secondary boolean operation with a straight vertical line followed by the script will give you the result.

Comment: @ToughGuy, in a closed path in Illustrator, there is no line between the first and last points. They occupy the same location. And as far as I can tell, there is no way to ensure that the start point will fall at the end of the vertical line he wants to delete. I would love to see your solution so I could better understand what you are talking about.

Comment: Well, I must say that question needs to show relevant example. The above example is easily solvable with the provided script.

Comment: @CrimsonCape I've updated the answer, let me know if my instructions are not clear, I'll demonstrate with images.

Comment: @ToughGuy: Hi, I understood the instructions however that same problem remains. The opening and closing point is not necessarily always on the vertical line. In some instances, it removed the horizontal line instead.

Comment: @CrimsonCape It seems unclear about what exactly do you want. You want to remove the right half of the object entirely OR you want to remove the part which intersected the object? Is it possible for you to send few examples so I can understand better

Comment: Hi, I got the issue. I was simplifying the path before running your script. When I simplified, it added extra anchor points in some cases in the vertical path which changes the path's beginning and ending point. When I am running right after using the Pathfinder tool, it effectively clears the vertical path. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Unfortunately, the situation is unsolved. The opening of closed path does work only on the left side, never on the right side. I investigated it further and while outlining the object, the starting and ending point is always on the right side therefore when I cut the shape, only left side has new starting and ending point. If I cut the left side out and keep the right side, the starting and ending point remains the same and the path does not open up as intended.

Comment: The opening of path depends on the first and last anchor points. If you are performing a boolean operation on the left side, it will open from the left side. There is a "Reverse path direction" command in the stroke pallete. It might be useful for you. But it in this case it won't affect anything. It's difficult to assist any further unless you provide a sample file.

Answer (score 2):

I found a trick, if you don't care much about the path quality. Maybe someone can get a better idea from this.

1. From the appearance panel → Clear Appearance
2. Add a stroke linear gradient from black/50% location to white/50% location

   [image: Gradient]
3. **Rasterize** it
4. Apply **Image Trace** selecting **Line Art** as preset. Illustrator only allows to put in an action the default tracing presets. There's a script in [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/65169/120647) to record a different preset but I couldn't make it work. Maybe it's because the Illustrator version.
5. **Expand**
6. Simplify if necessary from menu **Object** → **Path** → **Simplify**

[image]

All these steps can be recorded in one action and automate the work process, without the need to use the Direct selection tool or any other manual adjustment.

By saving these steps as a script in the Illustrator scripts folder, you can add the script from the File menu in an action.

Comment: How is this *better*, easier, faster, cleaner, etc.... than merely clicking the vertical path and hitting the delete key?

Comment: Don't take my text as a "rant" :) it's not at all. I'm merely curious when I see.. vector > Raster > Trace to get back to vector. That always seems overly counter-productive to me. In my world, sacrificing the quality of the original path is never an option to save literally 1 click and 1 key tap. That's all.

Comment: @Danielillo I read Scott's question as just that - a question. I'm not sure why you got defensive and feel the need to be insulting. You guys have both made (and continue to make) excellent contributions to our site and we would all love for this to continue.

Comment: I removed the unnecessary debate in the comments. Please [stay nice](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/conduct) and assume good intentions.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're making the rectangles one by one, selecting both shapes and hitting the Action and repeating this workflow on all thousands of shapes...

What I can think of:
You can cut everything. Then selecting all and making alignment and deleting de undesired line easily.

See the image below:

[image]

Comment: Not a bad idea, but based on this case, I assume that everything is in it's own doc (or at least needs to be in it's position that it's in).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. However, all the shapes are being created from separate images and in separate file and they are of different width and height so this option really won't work. So far the best solution is what @Danielillo suggested. I am working to make a script for the Black and White line art option.